# Linking CXX executable error-- /usr/bin/ld: cannot find

Tags: cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am building a hardware interface for my robot using the Dave Coleman's template package [ros_control_boilerplate](https://github.com/davetcoleman/ros_control_boilerplate)

I am having problems building my package. Relevant snippets of my CMakeLists.txt look like:

```
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_library(nymble_hw_interface src/nymble_hw_interface.cpp)
target_link_libraries(nymble_hw_interface ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(nymble_hw_control_loop src/nymble_hw_control_loop.cpp)
target_link_libraries(nymble_hw_control_loop
  nymble_hw_interface
  generic_hw_control_loop
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

install(TARGETS  
        nymble_hw_interface 
        LIBRARY DESTINATION
    ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION})

install(TARGETS
    nymble_hw_control_loop
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION})
```

On running catkin_make, I am getting the error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgeneric_hw_control_loop
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/rohin/catkin_ws/devel/lib/hardware/nymble_hw_control_loop] Error 1
make[1]: *** [nymblebot/hardware/CMakeFiles/nymble_hw_control_loop.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I am at a loss to understand why my generic_hw_control_loop library is not being linked when it is an installed library under the package ros_control_boilerplate.

Also I have listed ros_control_boilerplate as a build and run dependency in my package.xml

The executable I'm building contains :

```
#include <ros_control_boilerplate/generic_hw_control_loop.h>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238028/linking-cxx-executable-error---/usr/bin/ld:-cannot-find/) by [rohin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26768/rohin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 99 on 2016-06-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Issue solved.

I had messed some of my files. Hence catkin was looking in the wrong directory.

---

Originally posted by [rohin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26768/rohin/) with karma: 99 on 2016-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0